# Open source standard for decentralised connection between small social media sites

Tags: interop, standards, social-networking

**TLDR;** Is there a social media standard that behaves (cross-site) like email + profiles? This is so that multiple users of a few small social-media communities I plan to start don't experience lock-in.

Is there any standard protocol for communication between small internet communities with social network features in a way that doesn't need a centralized server?

The ideal protocol (for the task I plan to use it for) would support:

- Multimedia messaging between communities
- OAuth or similar support, (with real permission features)
- The use of profile pages, with the standard (but entirely optional) fields- (preferably in the same format as messages)
- Reply chains
- Cross community friending
- Cross community account association/disassociation
- Potential extension to support a client accessing these pages through HTTPS using only the standard without needing site-specific (URL) rules.
- Access to external applications (e.g games) (through OAuth?), but the user actually has control over what is shared. (I don't want a repeat of the Facebook not-leak, after all.)

I **don't** want support for Facebook integration or anything else remotely privacy-intruding, I just want users of my website to be able to communicate "in the modern way". I also wouldn't like a library unless it follows a standard that meets these criteria, and can be easily ported to other languages for language-independant use.

Comment: I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643277/is-there-an-open-source-social-media-network-site-framework), but not only is it almost being a decade old, the project having been abandoned for 6 years; that is also about building a social website, **not** an interoperability question like mine.

Comment: [This](//stackoverflow.com/questions/48320) question is also about implementation **not** standards for secure cross-communication .